# How to load same props on navigation of react component?

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-router v3` 
i have few dropdowns on home page and button to move on product page.
when user again come back to home page it should display same value which user had selected. but some how it reload all values.

Is there any way using which i can preserve value easily using react-router ?

```
<Route path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="product" >
            <IndexRoute component={Product}/>
            <Route path="offer">
                <IndexRoute component={OfferForm} />
                <Route path="confirm" component={OfferConfirm}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="immediate">
                <IndexRoute component={ImmediateOrderForm} />
                <Route path="confirm" component={OfferConfirm}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value while redirect or navigate to another page using params and you can get it there in the Component.

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/url', params: { name: edit } }} />;
```

get the value like below in home page

```
let name = this.props.location.params.name;
```

You can use history like below but I think both are same. Anyway you need to pass all the values to the relevant router page while calling.

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/url',
  params: { name: edit }
});
```

Hope this will help  . I dont think you can do it directly using react router.

Comment: This could be really tricky if no. of dropdowns increased, 
could it be possible with withRouter HOC or history ? i have't used yet so..

Answer (score 0):

**You need to store choosen settings in `localStorage` and restore them on reloading page.** You can use `redux` and [`redux-persist`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) for this.

You can also use the saved (shared between pages) values on the details page for *'see also similar ...'* section. It seems it can be done inside details query but I'd do it in a separate query (highly dynamic) - the detail view (main query) can be SSR-ed (with/without default similarities) which can be updated with fresh data after rehydrating/mounting/initial render.